# IntelliJ strange behavior of static import completion for org.junit.Assert.assertEquals

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

In IntelliJ, when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, it correctly offers to add static import for `assertNotEquals`:

[image]

But not for `assertEquals`:

[image]

Furthermore, when I press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>,
it doesn't offer `assertEquals`, only `assertNotEquals` and `assertArrayEquals`:

[image]

I have to add the static import by typing manually.
Even then, it doesn't help auto-completing, it only offers `assertNotEquals` and `assertArrayEquals` while typing.

Oddly, this only happens on my work PC in Windows. I had this problem since version 11, 12, 13, now I'm using version 14.3, community edition.

Why is this happening and how can I make it offer `assertEquals`?

Side note: I don't know if this is relevant,
but it used to offer `assertEquals` from `junit.framework` instead of `org.junit`. That was error prone and annoying,
so I disabled all imports from `junit.framework`.

Comment: Works for me.... I'd assume it's something with the classpath, but can't say  until I get it understood.

Comment: Yeah, works on my other PC too. I can't imagine what's in my env that might cause this. I have a pretty vanilla setup.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you have excluded `org.junit.Assert.assertEquals` in the settings. Open your settings and search for "imports". In **Editor / General / Auto Import** you can configure a list of classes and pacakges to **Exclude from Import and Completion**.